# C3P0 connection pool throws 'No suitable driver' on Tomcat when new WAR is uploaded

Tags: tomcat, c3p0

I have C3P0 code in the application, but the drivers are in tomcat/lib directory.

This obviously triggers a classloader issue. Everything is fine when the whole tomcat is restarted. But it fails with 'No suitable driver' when I just upload new WAR.

Comment: All worked in my setup before I moved the driver from the application (in pom.xml ro 'provided') to the tomcat8/lib folder

Answer (score 0):

Well, it does not help to call

```
Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver")
```

One needs to do this

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver());
```